# Works in Localhost but Not in server.Empty POST parameter received in PHP when android app send data to insert

Tags: java, php, android

I have just started learning developing android app.I have developed an android app that stores data into mysql database using php. Its working fine in localhost.Its able to insert data as POST parameters.But when i tried to do it in server its not inserting.I debugged it and found that the POST parameter received in PHP is empty.  Please can anybody help me !!

Comment: `have just started learning developing android app.`. You should also learn how to ask a question here. Pretty unclear what you are doing.

Comment: Please add your code to find problem ?